# give argparse arguments from within file (edited with better explanation of question)

Tags: command-line-arguments, argparse

A quick question:

If I would like to add arguments in argparse from within the file so that I can execute the file in for example Visual Studio, how should I do this?

The reason is both for learning and debugging.

For example, if I have this

```
parser.add_argument('-vid', '--video', type=str, help="Path to video file to be used for inference (conflicts with -cam)")
```

I have a script that I did not write and I would like to run it from VS to make changes and (hopefully not but probably as I'm new to python) debug my changes.
the script has a bunch of arguments (argpars) that I would like to "fill in" direct in VS to be able to run the script from VS.

If it's easier to delete the entire argpars-function this would be an option (I could add this again later when I'm done) but if it's possible to "fill them" direct in the code that would be great.

There is a way in VS to go through solution - options, but that makes editing a bit trickier.

So for example if (as above) there is a parser-argument for --video, could this in someway be added as (code-guessing/paraphrasing);

video_path = 'd:\path\to\video-file.mpg4'

--video = video_path

How would I do to add the path for the -vid when the file is open in VS to be able to run it from there?

Is there a way to add something like "if no -vid (from argparse) run with -vid (from path added in the code)?

Comment: I don't understand your question, especially its context.  But you might consider providing `--video` with a meaningful `default` value.  Or do test runs of the parser with `args = parser.parse_args('--video testpath'.split())`.  In VS there are ways of specifying commandline arguments to be used with the `run` command.

Comment: Hi!
Sorry, i´ll try to explain in a other way, i´ll edit the question.

Comment: '-vid' is just a flag string that the parser recognizes. It is not a python variable.  You cannot use it in any code.  After `args=parse_args()`, `args.video` should be `None` or a user supplied string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I found a way with pathlib setting up path(__file__).parent, but i´m not sure if thats the right way to go, and i´m not sure how to set it up if i would like multiple "parents" (being able to add for example both -vid and -other from within the script). As always, any ideas are welcome!